# Activity isn't called when clicking on a tab for the second time

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am developing one application and in which i have to display a five tabs and on each tab i am calling a different activity.And in my last tab i displaying menus.

**The main problem is that my activities are called only on tab changed events**.when i am clicking on last tab first time it displays a menu and after selecting any menu if i click on that tab again then nothing happens.

So how to solve this kind of problem? is there any other way to do this task?
 Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

**Here is my code:**

```
public class More extends ActivityGroup{

     Button btn1;
     ExpandableListView elw;
     Context ctx;
     public ListView modeList;
     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ctx=this;

           Toast.makeText(More.this,"in more",200).show();
           setContentView(R.layout.more);

           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           builder.setTitle("More Option");

            modeList = new ListView(this);
           String[] stringArray = new String[] { "About", "Settings","Invite By Message","Privacy Policy","Deactivate Account","Exit" };
           ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
           modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);


           builder.setView(modeList);
           final Dialog dialog = builder.create();

           dialog.show();
modeList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String item=(String) modeList.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(More.this,item,200).show();
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            setContentView(R.layout.about);
            dialog.dismiss();
          TabHost tabHost = welcome.self.getTabHost();
          tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);

              // tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
            break;
        case 1:
            setContentView(R.layout.settings);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
        case 2:
            setContentView(R.layout.messages);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
        case 3:
            setContentView(R.layout.policy);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
        case 4:
            Toast.makeText(More.this,"Deactivate the Account",200).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
        default:
             Toast.makeText(More.this,"Exit the application",200).show();
             dialog.dismiss();
             welcome.self.finish();
            }               
    }
});
```

Comment: It will be better if u show some code of your...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
modeList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String item=(String) modeList.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(More.this,item,200).show();
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            setContentView(R.layout.about);
            dialog.dismiss();
         // TabHost tabHost = welcome.self.getTabHost();-> Intent abc;

         // tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);---->abc.getClass(More.this , NewClass.class);

              // tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
            break;
        case 1:
            setContentView(R.layout.settings);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
        case 2:
            setContentView(R.layout.messages);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
        case 3:
            setContentView(R.layout.policy);
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
        case 4:
            Toast.makeText(More.this,"Deactivate the Account",200).show();
            dialog.dismiss();
            break;
        default:
             Toast.makeText(More.this,"Exit the application",200).show();
             dialog.dismiss();
             welcome.self.finish();
            }               
    }
});
```

Now your NewClass.java

```
public class NewClass extends TabActivit{


     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           setContentView(R.layout.newclass);

Resources ressources = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

        // Android tab
        Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, AndroidActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecAndroid = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("Android")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_android_config))
          .setContent(intentAndroid);

        // Apple tab
        Intent intentApple = new Intent().setClass(this, AppleActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecApple = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("Apple")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_apple_config))
          .setContent(intentApple);

        // Windows tab
        Intent intentWindows = new Intent().setClass(this, WindowsActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecWindows = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("Windows")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_windows_config))
          .setContent(intentWindows);

        // Blackberry tab
        Intent intentBerry = new Intent().setClass(this, BlackBerryActivity.class);
        TabSpec tabSpecBerry = tabHost
          .newTabSpec("Berry")
          .setIndicator("", ressources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_blackberry_config))
          .setContent(intentBerry);

        // add all tabs 
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecAndroid);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecApple);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecWindows);
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpecBerry);

        //set Windows tab as default (zero based)
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }

}


}
```

here are 4 tabs you can use as many as you want.
Register in android manifest.
Make sure your tabhost in layout file has the id same as in your code.

click right if you accept my answer.

Comment: i have already do that like one activity which extends the tabactivity as mention above.i think my question you have not understand.like in above code if 4th tab is clicked and the listview will display and according the item i need to do some action.that is perfect but the problem is that when the item is selected and according the new screen will open and i click the same current tab then it will not show me the listview.i need to how many time i click the same tab it will always need to open listview.

Answer (score 2):

```
TabHost tabs = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.TabHost01);

        tabs.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec spec1 = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

        spec1.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec1.setIndicator("TAB1");

        tabs.addTab(spec1);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec2 = tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
        spec2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec2.setIndicator("TAB2");

        tabs.addTab(spec2);
```

add this in your method, and for details take a look http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/.

let me know if you have problem , click right if it is solved. Your activity must contain layout.

Comment: i thing the switch cases you are using for dialog , let it redirect to open an activity which is extends to tabactivity

Comment: thanks,already i did same in my Apps as you mentioned in your link.i have used ActivityGroup,And in my switch case i don't want to open new activity but just i want to change my content view.that's i done already in above code.

Comment: did it help? why you want to have activity group

Comment: i want to show all 5 tabs in all activity.So i have use the activity group.

Comment: okay try this Intent abc ; abc.getClass(yourpresentclass.this , the new class.this); here  TabHost tabHost = welcome.self.getTabHost();
          tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);    , now in newClass declare the 5tabs , wherever you want to put new intent change it

Comment: When i call new intent as per your suggestion then new activity will open without tabs.And the tabs are created and handle in separate activity.so i don't want to declare the tabs again in new activity.

Comment: you can open newActivity with Tabs

Comment: can you explain or give code for open new activity with tabs.